# How do I plot a distance map in $R^2$ to a curve given in form $y=f(x)$?

Tags: plotting, computational-geometry, distance

As in the title, I'd like to display image using `DensityPlot` representing distance to a given curve, e.g., $y=x^2$.

I find it difficult to derive distance function to from a an arbitrary point to a curve (even for such simple quadratic function).

Is it possible to tell Mathematica to find numerically the distance to a given function from every $x,\,y$ location?

Comment: Not the easiest thing to do. Could use "fast marching" to get points of constant distance from the given curve, and color them accordingly. A notebook with some code can be found [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/07/navigating-the-blenheim-maze/).

Comment: Interesting approach, over kill tho :) thanks anyway!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe

```
rd = RegionDistance @ ParametricRegion[{x, x^2}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}]; 

ContourPlot[Evaluate@rd[{x, y}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
 Contours -> 10, Exclusions -> None, 
 Epilog -> {Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]][[1]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Simply beautiful, thank you @kglr :)

Comment: @Anonymous, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: I found another way, simpler to type but way harder for Mathematica:
func[x_] := x^2;
dist[x_, y_] := Sqrt[Minimize[(x - z)^2 + (y - func[z])^2, z][[1]]];
ContourPlot[dist[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]